# Modal for images javascript not working for second, third etc. image

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I created a slider based on w3schools and want each slide to open in a modal when clicked. However, only the first slide is clickable, rest is not working.

I tried to pass multiple ids to the `getdocumentbyid` function which doesn't work.

This is de html/php:

```
<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">4 / 5</div>
<img src="<?php echo $imgcount1;?>" id="myImg" class="opace">
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mySlides fade">
<div class="numbertext">4 / 5</div>
<img src="<?php echo $imgcount2;?>" id="myImg" class="opace">
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
    </div>
</div>
```

The script:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
img.onclick = function(){
modal.style.display = "block";
modalImg.src = this.src;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Wanted situation is to make every image clickable and showup in modal

Comment: You're assigning the same `id` to multiple elements. How is the browser supposed to know which one you're referring to? An `id` is supposed to be unique. Also, please [do not use w3schools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com) (and I will keep mentioning this until either me or the site is finally dead)

Comment: ID's have to be unique, so you're only binding the click event to one image. Use a class name or separate id's.

Comment: hi @ChrisG: i know the problem lies in the ID, i tried multiple ids (myImg,myImg1 etc.) however, i cannot store multiple ids in one getElementById(). How do i make this work for multiple ID's without repeating the code all the time?

Comment: Here's how: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/g06th7od/

Comment: @ChrisG: thanks, works completely. Respect!